# Can't print CryptoJS-encrypted ciphertext to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, cryptojs

I can't access the `encryptedData` variable with jQuery but in `alert` it works!!!

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/aes.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var textToEncrypt = "textToEncrypt";
    var secretPhrase  = "secretPhrase";
    var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(textToEncrypt, secretPhrase);
    $('#data').text(encryptedData);  
    alert(encryptedData);
  });
</script>

<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encryptedData` is a CipherParams object containing various properties such as `ciphertext`, `salt` and `iv`. jQuery's `text` function takes this object and tries to assign it directly to the element. `alert` on the other hand first stringifies it. You probably want:

```
$('#data').text(encryptedData.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Artjom B. (y)